# Apache named vhost not catching requests that should go to it

Tags: apache, vhosts

I have an Apache server with a group of name-based virtual hosts on it. Requests are sent to the server via an Apache reverse proxy, which forwards all requests for these site names to port 80 on the backend server. While most of these sites appear to be working fine, one vhost is failing to pick up requests for its designated site name, and these are instead being served by the default vhost.

Here's the configuration for the problematic host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.dev.awesome.ac.nz
   ServerAdmin netaccount@auckland.ac.nz

   ErrorLog logs/awesomeacnz.error.log
   CustomLog logs/awesomeacnz.access.log common

   Alias / /var/www/html/awesomeacnz/
</VirtualHost>
```

And here's the output of the Apache vhost diagnostic:

```
[aful018@wprappdev01 ~]$ sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
_default_:443          wprappdev01.its.auckland.ac.nz (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:74)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server asblog.auckland.ac.nz (/etc/httpd/conf.d/academicservices.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost asblog.auckland.ac.nz (/etc/httpd/conf.d/academicservices.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost www.dev.awesome.ac.nz (/etc/httpd/conf.d/awesomeacnz.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost www.dev.auckland.ac.nz (/etc/httpd/conf.d/insideword.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost spearblog.dev.auckland.ac.nz (/etc/httpd/conf.d/spear.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost wordpress-theme.dev.auckland.ac.nz (/etc/httpd/conf.d/theme-dev.conf:1)
Syntax OK
```

I can't see anything in the above that suggests a problem, but when I send a request for anything on www.dev.awesome.ac.nz the request is served by the vhost for asblog.auckland.ac.nz, which as you can see above is the default host.

Does anyone know why the vhost defined above would not be matching requests for that site? The NameVirtualHost directive in httpd.conf is set to *:80, and other similarly- (not identically-) configured sites on the same server are working fine.

The server is apache 2.2.15 running on Red Hat EL 6.1.